# Extracting friend's list using Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I am stuck with this issue since awhile now. I am trying to retrieve my friends list (who are using this app, ofcourse). The SDK version is 3.2.3. The code does pull out information from my profile, but does not pull anything from my friends profiles. Though i am using the scope permission parameter with my login. Following is my index.php file :

```
  require_once('facebook.php');

  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'xxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxx'
    //'allowSignedRequest' => false
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>



    if($user_id) {

      try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($user_profile); //prints my profile
        echo "</pre>";

      foreach ($user_profile["data"] as $friend) {
       echo $friend['id'];
         echo $friend['name'];
      }


        echo '<br><a href=' . $facebook->destroySession() . '>Logout</a>';



      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {



      }   
    } else {

      $params = array(
        'scope' => 'public_profile, user_friends, email',
       );
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }



  </body>
</html>

How can i just print my friend's list? (those friends whose permission i have!)
```

Comment: You have to do a request to /me/friends to get friends

Comment: It is supported: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends .

Comment: Check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/events

Comment: @codemode  i have used your code its  working ..how to remove login options before showing results.how to remove login options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
```

to

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,friends','GET');
```

for example.

Comment: i have used code in what posted in question its working.always login options asking before show friends list .how to remove that ?

Comment: @Thennarasu **You can't!** That's the whole principle of OAuth